# getting java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: java, oracle

i am trying to run the below query i am getting the a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected here is the query

```
select * from schedule where to_date(SHDL_STRT_TIME,'dd-MON-yy HH24:mi:ss')                                            
IN('11-Jan-15 20:30:00','11-Jan-15 08:00:00','11-Jan-15 20:00:00')
```

and `shdl_strt_time` is of type `DATE` object  it works fine in sqldeveloper but from application its not working

Please clarify where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHDL_STRT_TIME` is already of type `DATE`, so you don't need to use `TO_DATE()` over it.

But a `TO_CHAR()` which is what you needed!!!

Also `MON` gives month as `JAN`... SO, you need a `Mon` for `Jan`

```
select * from schedule where to_char(SHDL_STRT_TIME,'dd-Mon-yy HH24:mi:ss')                                            
IN('11-Jan-15 20:30:00','11-Jan-15 08:00:00','11-Jan-15 20:00:00')
```

Finally, elegant solution could be,

```
select * from schedule where SHDL_STRT_TIME IN(:DATE1, :DATE2, :DATE3)
```

In `JDBC`, bind the values using `java.sql.Date`. Because, `Mon` may not be `Jan` is Non-American databases!!! Also, you might miss the index, if you perform `to_char()` over it..

Comment: Thanks ravi for your reply.I tried the above one its working in the sql developer but if i executing from the application i am not getting any data happy thing is i am not getting the exception.But it is not fetching any data.I don't know what might be the reason

Comment: Try the format as **Mon** , for month name.! I updated the answer.